# Extract character from string in "td" tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table:

```
<tr>
    <td id="rk1">First RK</td>
    <td id="rk1_1">09231</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="rk2">Second RK</td>
    <td id="rk2_1">60234</td>
    <td id="rk2_2">69260</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="rk3">Third RK</td>
    <td id="rk3_1">30224</td>
    <td id="rk3_2">30302</td>
    <td id="rk3_3">20280</td>
    <td id="rk3_4">82122</td>
</tr>
```

And I want to extract content like this:

```
result1 = 23 //("rk1 / column 1 / character 3" and "rk2 / column 1 / character 4" )
result2 = 62 //("rk2 / column 2 / character 1" and "rk3 / column 3 / character 3")
result3 = 91 //("rk2 / column 2 / character 2" and "rk3 / column 4 / character 3")
...
```

Use array (condition) to extract string:

```
("rk1/1/3 and rk2/1/4", "rk2/2/1 and rk3/3/3", "rk2/2/2 and rk3/4/3",...)
```

How can i do this task?

Comment: What logic lies behind the character(s) you need to retrieve, and are you wanting this client-side or server-side? When you tried to implement this yourself, how far did you get? Where did you get stuck? What went wrong, and in what way was it wrong? Are there any errors reported in your attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with the code below, but the way you format your parameters is kind of weird, and may produce errors if not formatted correctly.

```js
var parameters = ["rk1/1/3 and rk2/1/4", "rk2/2/1 and rk3/3/3", "rk2/2/2 and rk3/4/3"];

// For each set of parameters, execute extract_content
for (var i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++) {
  console.log('Result for "' + parameters[i] + '":');
  console.log(extract_content(parameters[i]));
}

function extract_content(params) {
  // Split selections, to get something like ["rk1/1/3", "rk2/1/4"]
  var selections = params.split(' and '),
      res = '';
  // For each selection
  for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
    // Split it on slashes, to get ["rk1", "1", "3"]
    var parts = selections[i].split('/'),
        // Get the element with ID "rk1_1"
        elem = document.getElementById(parts[0] + '_' + parts[1]);
    // If the element exists
    if (elem) {
      // Add the character at position X to the result
      res += elem.textContent.trim()[parts[2] - 1];
    }
  }
  // Convert result to a number and return it
  return res;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="rk1">First RK</td>
    <td id="rk1_1">09231</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="rk2">Second RK</td>
    <td id="rk2_1">60234</td>
    <td id="rk2_2">69260</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="rk3">Third RK</td>
    <td id="rk3_1">30224</td>
    <td id="rk3_2">30302</td>
    <td id="rk3_3">20280</td>
    <td id="rk3_4">82122</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Line : 2,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected 'var' (T_VAR)

Comment: @comez Oh, are you using PHP for that? That's JavaScript. You mentioned JavaScript in your question's tags

Comment: oh sorry, can you explain your script?

Comment: @comez I added comments to my code

Comment: this script do not show zero number :)

Comment: @comez Then, `return res;` instead of `+res`. (You'll get a string instead of a number, which hides leading zeroes).